TV-Show: Man released from prison after 20 years being innocent. 2015 or 2016. 3 seasons
In the first chapter a Man (the starring character) is released from prison after 20 years being innocent. His innocence is not yet clear. But he got released after some new evidence. His lawyer (boyfriend of his younger sister) make a short speech about justice and the Man, the ex-prisoner, says some words.
The Man has a younger sister. I think she was 11 when his older brother got in prison. Years later, she spent years struggling to get his brothers' freedom.
When the Man gets out, he was taken by his sister to their mother's house where there lives also his mother, step-father and a brother. Later he will have some problems with his brother (I think they are step-brothers).
The Man is having serious problems to fit in the town where he lives, cause people treat him as a murderer.
Very good acting in this TV-Show.

Rectify

Daniel Holden must put his life back together after serving 19 years on Georgia's Death Row before DNA evidence calls his conviction into question.




The main characters from wikipedia


Daniel Holden, convicted for the rape and strangulation murder of his teenage girlfriend Hanna but later released from prison after the discovery of conflicting DNA evidence.
Amantha Holden, Daniel's younger sister who has always believed in his innocence.
Janet Talbot, Daniel's mother.
  Adelaide Clemens as Tawney Talbot, Teddy's wife, and Daniel, Amantha, and Jared's deeply religious sister-in-law.
Jon Stern, Daniel's new lawyer. He did not defend Daniel in the rape and murder trial. He is in a relationship with Daniel's sister.
Ted "Teddy" Talbot, Jr., Daniel's stepbrother and Tawney's husband. His father married Daniel's mother after Daniel's father died, while Daniel was in prison.
Ted Talbot, Sr., Daniel's stepfather. He was once a worker at the tire store owned by Daniel's father but took over after his death



No problem, glad I could help!
